# How can I italicize foreign language words in MS Word (2010)?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, language

I've made my undergraduate thesis using Word 2010 and I've set language to my country language (I've downloaded spelling and grammar for my country language too).

My college has a rule to type foreign language in italic. Is there any quick way using a Word 2010 feature to achieve this?

Comment: What foreign language are you using?

Comment: Foreign language means any language other than my country language (I set to Indonesian). In find and replace menu, there is option "Sound like (English)". Actually, I want to use this feature. But, I have to fill what words I'm replacing for. What I want is, replacing all English words, not particular English words (underlined by red line), so I need not to fill certain word in "Find what" option. Any approach would be considered.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t understand what you are saying about "Sound like (English)", but in “Find and Replace”
you need to specify text and/or a format to find –– not necessarily both,
so you don’t need to fill in particular words:

[image]